# How to run a Python script in a remote computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtual-machine

I have a Virtual computer in the Cloud and I have a Python code (and all the required libraries) in that computer.

I have also access to the C: drive of that computer from my local machine, so I can access the files, code locally, then save it on the VM.

I can also access the file via PowerShell and execute it, but if do that, it will run on the local machine, not in the Virtual.

Is there a way of forcing the code to run in the computer where it is stored and report the outputs back to the shell where it was called from (without implementing an API)?

Comment: Is your virtual computer in the cloud running linux or windows ? With linux you should be able to use ssh, with windows i don't know.

Comment: On *Win* you could run the remote file via the *IPC* share, but as a service.

Comment: You can use SSH and run the python program remotely in your cloud server (Assuming that you have Linux based operating system in your cloud server).
In rare case if your remote server is running windows, you can also install SSH in there and follow the same approach.

Comment: It is a Windows machine, and I don't think that I can install anything to it.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running on the server?
The newer versions of Powershell ship with ssh.

Comment: It is a Windows 10, not a server.

Comment: Even better. I'm fairly certain windows 10 ships with ssh.
Do you have any way of executing commands on the machine?
Or do you know the creds of a user on it, then you should be able to ssh in.